# Popular this week - Popular this month - functionality with PHP

Tags: php, algorithm

Suppose a table `videos`

```
id        | name         | views
----------+--------------+-----------
1         | Video1       | 52
2         | Video2       | 150
...
```

For getting the video which is popular/most viewed this week, I could create another table: `videoviews`

```
id        | foreign_key  | viewed_on
----------+--------------+-----------
1         | 1            | 10/12/2018
2         | 1            | 09/12/2018
...
```

From this table, I can easily get the data for last week/last month etc. That's not an issue.

**Problem:**
Suppose I have 1000 Videos and Each video gets 100 Views per day.
My `videoviews` table will have 100000 records each day.

I know this is not the best way to achieve this functionality. Just wondering what is?

I found these on SO but..

[How to get most visited posts of the week?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116117/how-to-get-most-visited-posts-of-the-week)

[Popular Today, This Week, This Month - Design Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466150/popular-today-this-week-this-month-design-pattern)

Comment: create more columns ... `visit_this_week` and then cronjob to reset to 0 on Monday at midnight?

Comment: Thought of that too.. but I need data for month also. So, in 30 days, I will have 300000 records. which is not good.

Comment: ? You'd have the same amount of rows as your video count..?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs OP appears to be logging each individual view, not a summary count.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs For every view on a video i will have a new record on`videocount`.
But I surely reduce that by adding a new column `views` in the `videocount` table and then add all the views for a particular data.

Comment: @Saurabh what it not make more sense to just have a column instead of a whole table per hit?

Comment: that's what i said two thumbs :-P

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the answer you linked to as [Popular Today, This Week, This Month - Design Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466150/popular-today-this-week-this-month-design-pattern) ?

Comment: @CD001 I thought there could be a better way!!

Comment: Top rated answer on that question seems logical to me... \*shrugs\*

Comment: Seemed logical to me too, that's the reason I posted the link on my question. I wasn't clear about the concept though. But now I am. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem: Suppose I have 1000 Videos and Each video gets 100 Views per day. My videoviews table will have 100000 records each day.

Do you *need* a complete record of each individual view?

You could, instead, use a counter approach, where you store one row per video per day, and simply increment its value when a new row comes in. This is granular enough to provide useful per-day analytics, without having to store a million rows for a million video views.

Comment: So if I have 1000 videos, and even if I get hits on all the videos, I will have only 1000 records per day in my table right?

Comment: @Saurabh Right. Remember that with proper indexing and appropriate hardware, a SQL table can handle billions of rows.

Comment: And clearing the table after the month gets over. Awesome.

Comment: If that fits your needs, sure. You could also cram down the metrics after a while - perhaps after a month you store it at a per-month level instead of daily.

Comment: There's a reason you have 134k reps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add extra columns called `views` and `start_date` on your videoviews table.

On hitting the page with the video, fetch the views, increment, and update where the week starts with `start_date`.

Only one row is required per week. You can also remove old weeks if you like.

Comment: updated, this should work and save you quite a few rows